# I can't place my Mocked class files in the src/main/test folder?

Tags: java, spring, maven, testing, mocking

I have a mocked class which simply extends a class in src/main/java/a/. It is configured by my test configuration xml:

```
<bean id="myService" class="a.b.c.MyService">
</bean>
```

My build was fine when my mocked class lived in src/main/java/a/. When I moved it to src/test/java/a/, my build breaks and IntelliJ tells me that it can't find the file. Can I not stick mock classes in the test directory? I don't need those mock classes to end up in the war.

Comment: Do you need to create actual mock classes, and package them in a war? Why not use a mocking framework and create at runtime?

Comment: We are getting there, this is a stop gap solution for now.

Comment: An incorrect spring conf cannot cause compile error, so I am going to assume you are getting it when running the tests. Can you post the error/exception that you are getting?

Comment: `src/main/test?` Do you mean `src/test`?

Answer (score 1):

By default files in your src will look in src/main/java. The will not look at files in src/test/java .

In IntelliJ you could assign that one package as a src directory. That isn't ideal.

If this is only a temporary solution as mentioned in the comment just put your mocked service in the src/main/Java directory.

Comment: If its a maven project the src/test/java folder will be part of the classpath during the test lifecycle. If you import it as a macen project in intellij this is setup correctly normally

Comment: There issue is general IDE resolution, not specific to test runners.